# Shape Renderer Increasing Square Size Not Uniform

Tags: android, libgdx

So I have an actor object I extended that will either draw a square or a circle, every frame it increases in size by 0.1.

When I draw circle it increases in size correctly and grows on screen, however when I draw a rect it jumps in size every 2.0 increments. I was wondering if anyone else had seen this behaviour.

Here is the simple code I use to draw the shapes.

```
  float size = 10.0f;

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

        ShapeRenderer r = new ShapeRenderer();

        r.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        r.setColor(Color.RED);

        //r.circle(this.getX() - (size / 2), this.getY() - (size / 2), size);  //this increases correctly
        r.rect(this.getX() - (size / 2), this.getY() - (size / 2), size, size);  //this doesnt

        r.end();

        size += 0.1f;

    }
```

So you can see what I mean I took some vids:

Circle : https://youtu.be/TtLcMxUCKb0

Square : https://youtu.be/UUGNfSpotKo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me like the square is expanding the least amount it can, 1 pixel at a time, it just looks a bit different from the circle since the circle does more than just expand 1 pixel to each side It has to the circle always look as round as possible, so updates a bit more often, shifting around a few pixel but not expanding.

Comment: So would changing the resolution of the window change this?

Comment: I can't be certain this is the actual problem from the videos you linked, but if this is the case there's nothing you can do apart from increasing the resolution. I would test to see if this is the problem, though.

Comment: try with a bigger increment, I guess your square is just too small to perceive any change